# PHP How to get rid of new line character in multiline string declaration, EOD method doesn't work

Tags: php, string, declaration, multiline

In PHP, I have 2 strings coming from an external source, where each contain 32x32 1s or 0s.
Because it's a requirement, I need it to be formatted as 32x32, because each one of those bits represent a pixel in a frame.

The problem I'm facing, is that I need to do bitwise logic on every single one of those 1s or 0s in paralell, because one affects the other.
In PHP, as far as I know, my only option is to make them into an array, where each bit is 1 index by adding commas after every bit, and then explode it into an array. (But ofc feel free to prove me wrong :) )
However, when I try to explode the string, the newline characters get included on every 32nd (last bit of the row) bit in the array that was created by the explosion.

I have tried the $image = <<<EOD ... EOD; method of getting around it, but it's no bueno.
My question would be, is there a neat way to get access to each bit of data bit by bit at the same time on both images, so that I can do some bitwise math?

My current EOD method: ($image1 and $image2 are the same format, let me only paste in image 1 declaration).

```
$image1 = <<<EOD
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    EOD;
```

Then the explosion:

```
$image_array = explode(',', $image1);
```

Creates this output (section taken out, so I don't need to list all 1024 bits here, but the point is, every 32nd bit has a newline character at the end).

```
    [33] => 0
    [34] => 0
    [35] => 0
    [36] => 0
    [37] => 0
    [38] => 0
    [39] => 0
    [40] => 0
    [41] => 0
    [42] => 0
    [43] => 0
    [44] => 0
    [45] => 0
    [46] => 0
    [47] => 0
    [48] => 0
    [49] => 0
    [50] => 0
    [51] => 0
    [52] => 0
    [53] => 0
    [54] => 0
    [55] => 0
    [56] => 0
    [57] => 0
    [58] => 0
    [59] => 0
    [60] => 0
    [61] => 0
    [62] => 0
    [63] => 0
    [64] =>
0
```

Also, as a bonus question: Is there an, in my use case, even better solution, where I don't need to insert commas after every single bit in the declaration? That would be amazing if there was.
Thank you in advance guys, looking forward to your answers. :)

Comment: You want to use a two dimensional array to store the data. It makes no sense to first create a string and to explode that to create the arrays. Create the arrays directly and your problem is gone.

Comment: Only problem with that, is the interface gives me strings. So it's not possible to start with a 2dim array sadly. Then ofc it would be easy :)

Comment: Your question never mentions any such "interface". In contrary: you explicitly phrase that you yourself create that string using "heredoc" notation.

Comment: Well now it does :P
Sorry for confusion. But the point is, we start from 2 strings.

Comment: From your description is not clear what exactly is the input and what should be the output. Does the input already contain commas and newlines?

Comment: No it doesn't. The string is only formatted 32x32, plain 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the input format actually is more than questionable. If it is meant to describe a 32*32 matrix, then those trailing commas do not make any sense.

But if you cannot fix that issue, then just implement a primitive parser which does what you need:

```
<?php
$input = <<<EOD
0,0,0,
0,1,1,
1,0,0
EOD;

$output = [];
foreach (explode("\n", $input) as $y => $line) {
  $output[$y] = [];
  foreach(explode(",", $line) as $x => $cell) {
    if ($cell != "") {
      $output[$y][$x] = $cell; 
    }
  }
}

print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )
)
```

Certainly other approaches exist, but none is better than the other, *except* if you can name a reason...

Answer (score 0):

Can you just map the array to be only numeric?

```
function cleanup($a) {
    return preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $a);
}
$image_array = array_map('cleanup',explode(",", $image1));
```